# How to disable csrf for token based authentication and enable it for browser?

Tags: jhipster

The gateway serves an angular application which attaches CSRF token to each request; it is ok. When I send a password grant type request from mobile (emulated by postman), there is an exception "invalid CSRF token", I think the request is token based and should not depend on CSRF.

I check the source code and found it possible to disable CSRF in SecurityConfiguration.java file, but it will affect angular app if disable it.

I searched online, and someone suggests set up another set of routes for the mobile app. But I think the jhipster microservices framework may support it out-of-box.

How to support CSRF for browser-based application and disable it for token-based authentication?

Comment: Have you considered having 2 gateways: one for browsers and one for mobiles and dealing this case in micro services based on token issuer?

Comment: thanks Gaël, sounds great and aggressive for me, does that mean I need to double others like UAA, registry for each of gateway?

Comment: No you don't need